# Why does my AdMob Banner shows an Ad in the Expo Client but not in the final Build?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, admob

I have a Problem with my React Native App. I'm using Expo, and the Banner i've included (via Google AdMob) shows an add when using the App over the Expo Client. But now i have built the App for the PlayStore, but the Banner is just white. I haven't found any solutions for now, since this is a rarely discussed topic.

This is the Banner Component i've included in my App.js File:

```
<AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="fullBanner"
  adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3609177996275417/1082785682"
  testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
  didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError}
/>
```

As mentioned this Banner shows perfectly results in the Expo Client, but the APK shows only a white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already try using the test adUnidID "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" from [Test Ads Amob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) ?, if that doesn't work then you can have a problem, if you ads doesn't show then it's normal, it can take up to 3 days for admob to be consistent

Comment: Then it's working, give it some time for the real ads to appear . It can depend on your location

Comment: Is it normal for it to take longer than 3 days? I've been waiting 5 days even though the test adUnitID loads

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem :( Expo show it, but in not in the released apk.
Wating now three days.